# Web Form Design - How to speed up?

Tags: html, forms, webforms, input

I am just going to be honest and say that I *hate* building web forms.  I am a programmer, not a designer but frequently get stuck building input forms for various web applications.  I would really like to find a utility for doing this in a more visual manner.  The problem I have found in the past with products like this (*cough cough* Dreamweaver! *cough cough*) is that they kick out such awful code that you spend nearly as much time cleaning up the code as you would writing it.

So my needs are: something to greatly expedite form building and design while still maintaing the integrity of the code.  Does such an application exist?  OSX applications preferred, but I would still be interested to know about things on the Windows side.

The answer to the question could very well save my sanity.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you explored the possibility of moving some of these apps towards MVC?  It can assist quite a bit in generating forms for basic CRUD, and MVC2 adds further templating support.

For example, say you want a View (page) which edits your `Customer` Model (business-object).  You can use the HTML Helper `EditorForModel()` to generate the full Form.  The default HTML is bare-bones, but with templates and customization you can get a fairly rich generated Form from very little code.

Also, consider alternative View Engines for MVC.  The default MVC View Engine looks like WebForms to a degree (your .aspx files will be littered with `<%= %>` tags), but others can provide a lot of syntactical sugar to the markup.

Comment: I am actually moving towards an M-V-C platform, particularly for building web applications that collect data.  Code Igniter has a very nice system for generating web form content based on database schema.  It definitely saves time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to add a dependency to a massive expensive JS lib, then [Ext Designer](http://www.sencha.com/products/designer/) is pretty cool.

Comment: Wow, that does look very cool but as you said fairly expensive.